# How to add datagridview row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm getting this error, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." which I think the reason is because I don't have a row and I'm placing a value in it.

is this correct?

```
DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {0})
```

basically what I'm doing is grouping a set of data and copy it to another table.

```
For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
    Dim DGV2Max1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    DGV2Max1.DataPropertyName = "Max" & j
    DGV2Max1.HeaderText = "Max" & j
    DGV2Max1.Name = "Max" & j
    DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DGV2Max1)
Next

For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Step 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value = j Then
         DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {0})
         DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Max" & j).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: What line does it say the error is on?

Comment: in DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Max" & j).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value

Comment: Either you don't have `Cells` or `Rows`.  Check (debug) the `DataGridView2` and query the `RowCount`.  If there are `Rows`, check that a row has `Cells`

Comment: you are correct, my bad. I declared another loop for dgv 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the same numbered row in each DataGridViews through `i`. This won't work if a row isn't added to `DataGridView2` each iteration.

Rather than trying to use the same row in each, find the last row in `DataGridView2` & use that:

```
For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Step 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value = j Then
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {0})
            DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("Max" & j).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code

```
 Dim dgv2 As Integer = 0
    For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Step 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Group").Value = j Then
                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {0})
                DataGridView2.Rows(dgv2).Cells("Max" & j).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("X_Pitch").Value
                dgv2 += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
```